# Move Text to Column in Excel with VB Script

Tags: excel, vbscript, copy, spreadsheet, paste

I have a large excel spreadsheet with records. Each record is 12 rows.  I need them moved to columns. Every twelve rows need to be copied into the same column matching up. Each row will be its own column. I need the script to open the workbook, execute the task, then save the workbook with the new arrangement.

The spreadsheet is very large, so I need for the script to loop all the way thru the sheet. At the end of the script I want the first twelve rows to be 1 record spread across 12 columns.  This is what I have thus far:

```
Dim xlApp
Dim xlSheet1
Dim xlBook1

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\users\am2878\desktop\Exchange Audit Log.xls"

Set xlBook1 = xlApp.Workbooks("Exchange Audit Log.xls")
Set xlSheet1 + xlBook1.Worksheet("Exchange Audit Log")

xlApp.Application.Visible = True

xlSheet1.Range("A1:A12").Cut

xlSheet1.Range("A1:L1").Paste

Loop

xlBook1.SaveAs "C:\users\am2878\desktop\Exchange Audit Log.xls", xlNormal, "","",False,False
xlApp.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you're looking for is called ["transpose"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). In Excel it's implemented as a parameter of the [`PasteSpecial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) method. You can't paste into cells you just cut out, though, so you need to paste it somewhere else:

```
Const xlAll  = -4104
Const xlNone = -4142

...

xlSheet1.Range("A1:A12").Cut
xlBook1.Sheets(2).PasteSpecial xlAll, xlNone, , True
```

If you need to modify the original sheet, you can then move the transposed data back to the source sheet:

```
xlBook1.Sheets(2).Range("A1:L1").Cut
xlSheet1.Activate
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
xlApp.ActiveSheet.Paste
```